Next.js setup to minify all css class names - both modules and global styles?
I have a next.js version 14 setup and I want to minify all class names - both modules and global styles - for production. So far, I have found such tools:

@nimpl/classnames-minifier - tried, works well except it's just for scss modules.
mangle-css-class-webpack-plugin - tried, requires specific class names pattern to minify. Works by replacing strings from js bundle, so it can replace even raw JS code. It doesn't find your class names from (s)css files.
next-optimized-classnames - works only with modules.

I also haven't managed to figure out how to define custom rules in next.js webpack config.
This is my configuration:
import classnamesMinifierImport from '@nimpl/classnames-minifier';

const withClassnamesMinifier = classnamesMinifierImport.default;

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: "export",
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: {
      ssr: true,
      displayName: false,
      minify: true,
    },
  },
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: { and: [/\.(js|ts|md)x?$/] },
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });

    // This rule results in error:
    // "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders"
    // Without it, it is alright, but again, @nimpl/classnames-minifier minifies
    // only modules
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: {
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
              exportLocalsConvention: 'camelCase',
            },
          },
        },
        'sass-loader',
      ],
    });

    return config;
  }
};

export default withClassnamesMinifier({
  disable: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
})(nextConfig);


I also use custom postcss config, do I need to connect it in webpack config if I override css default configuration?
How do I override default css config to add some functions but not to lose any default needed functionality?
Most importantly, how do I minify both css module and global styles class names, so that they are not intersected (these tools should be in sync)?
Also, I use scss.
Please, share your experience, configuration, sources etc.
Thank you!
